# Show Current Function on Toolbar in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, customization, toolbar

I wish to show the current function my cursor is in.  I sorely miss this feature from VS6, I have tried customizing the toolbars but it should be no surprise I can't find it within the maze of hundreds of toolbar items, does anyone know what it is called and where its located?  Or if its possible?

Let me give you an example.  I'm debugging and see a variable is set to a certain value, I need to examine where this is set, so I search for variable name, Ctrl-F, F3, F3, F3, when the cursor is moved to the next result and if its in the middle of function I need to know very quickly what function its in, scrolling or any mouse interaction is a major slowdown in this process, I use the keyboard 90% of the time during my dev.

PS: note to visual studio developers.  When you toolbar item list contains over 5,000 items it might be time to make it searchable lol!

Comment: True on the PS, but when your methods are so long you forget which one you're in it might be time to refactor!

Comment: You can highlight the line your cursor is on. Would that help? I can't imagine, because I've honestly never lost sight of my cursor before in an IDE...

Comment: Will: what do you mean by "true on the PS", what is the PS?  Refactoring a finished project that is 300k lines is not an option, and a complete waste of time, rewriting so you more easily know what function your in?  Cody:  I'm not losing sight of my cursor, the issue is when editing functions, or quickly moving around in the source (searching for variables and such) it would be very benificial to see the current function the cursor is in, I added an example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010, the code editor window has a toolbar at the top called the "Navigation Bar".  In C++, C#, and VB the right-hand drop down in the Navigation bar is dynamically updated to reflect the current function or method that the cursor is in.  You can read more about the navigation bar here:

- [How to: Navigate Code and Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w13x3hh.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, that was it, I must have turned it off when setting options at one point.  Now the issue I have is it doesn't show up for all of my source files?  And is there anyway to put this on a toolbar?  Its quite annoying to lose another line of displayed code in the editor when I have 90% of the window title bar blank, and 50% of the toolbar area completely wasted and where it could be.