# Enable method navigation bar in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In the past in Visual Studio I saw a dropdown that showed in which method my mouse cursor is currently placed in the code editor. This entire dropdown is now no longer visible (editing a `.aspx.vb` file for example). I can't find anywhere how to enable it again.

I already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833410/show-current-function-on-toolbar-in-visual-studio-2010).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the 'Navigation Bar' checkbox in `Options -> Text Editor -> All languages -> General`.