# How to enable comboboxes for quick jump into code, in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2019 (and older) there are three combobox for jumping quickly to a praticular portion of code, I don't have them, how they can be enabled ?
I have already updated VS to the latest version 16.10.4

[image: comboboxes for quick jump into code]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587411/enable-method-navigation-bar-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Thnks, it worked